# How to use the Windows event using Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxtjs3, windows-error-reporting

Hi I wanted to add a global windows error event listener to catch all errors in the UI using NUXT 3 so I added the below code in my menu.vue file which is always called. I am using the composition API

```
<template>
{{ error}}
</template>
    
<script setup lang="ts">
    let error: any = ref();
    window.addEventListener("error", function (ev) {
      error = ev; //get the event object
      ev.preventDefault; //this means dont stop the page from running
    });
    </script>
```

But i get the error 500
window is not defined. My menu file is a component so I dont understand why there is a problem?
Regards Neale

Comment: Neale, have you a look at error handling documentation of nuxt?
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling